# Is there is a way to add role to someone who has mentioned in a message in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

**This is my current code**

```
let person = message.mentions.users.first()
if (person === null) {
 message.channel.send('Please mention someone')
 return
}
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === "Muted")
person.roles.add(role)
message.channel.send(`${person.username} has been muted`)
person.send('You has been muted in DoGame')
```

it's not working for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

`person` returns a User object of the first mentioned user. You cannot add roles to a user, but only to a `GuildMember` - This can be done using `message.mentions.members.first()`.

#### Final Code

```js
const person = message.mentions.members.first()
if (person === null) {
 message.channel.send('Please mention someone')
 return
}
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === "Muted")
person.roles.add(role)
message.channel.send(`${person.user.username} has been muted`)
person.send('You has been muted in DoGame')
```

Comment: Message sending is working fine, but member didn't get any roles.

Comment: Read what I said, please.

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between `GuildMember` and `User`.

[GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) :

- Represents a member of a guild on Discord
- Properties : `guild`, `joinedAt`, `user`.. that are guild specific.
- You can access User from GuildMember by `<GuildMember>.user`

[User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) :

- Represents a user on Discord
- Properties : `id`, `username`, `createdAt`... that are not guild specific.

And you're getting `User` from mentions and trying to add role to `User` instead of `GuildMember`.

```js
const person = message.mentions.members.first();
```

This ^^^ will give you `GuildMember` and If you want to access User - `person.user`

Example : for username
You can do like `person.user.username`.